# How to check if a commit's changes made it into a branch (with squashed commits) content-wise?

Tags: git

I would like to check if the changes in some commit `target-commit` anywhere in the tree are already part of some branch `upstream`. But, not by comparing the name or the patch of individual commits. That would not work in my setting, because `upstream` may contain squashed commits, such that a squashed commit may contain more changes then `target-commit` and may have a modified commit message.

In other words:
I would like to check if a certain commit `target-commit` could be cherry-picked onto some branch `upstream` without any conflicts and would result in no changes (basically an empty commit). Idealy without changing the working tree or index state. Are you aware of any built-in mechanism in git which archieves this behavior?

As an alternative approach to reach the goal I considered `git cherry`. It does not seem to work in this case, because it compares the changes of individual commits. If these commits differ content-wise (due to an earlier squash), the `target-commit` is not recognized as being part of `upstream`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Cherry-picking these commits will result in a merge conflict (because the old content is not identical and the context is different). How would Git know if a line originated from that commit or it's an identical line somewhere else in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no completely reliable automatic way to tell.

The simplest test is to run `git cherry-pick` and see if Git says that, after merging, there is nothing left to do.  If so, the effect of the commit in question is already in place—well, *probably*.

If you get merge conflicts, the effect of the commit *may or may not be present*, and inspecting the merge conflicts will *probably* tell you whether it is.

If the cherry-pick succeeds by incorporating the effect of the commit, it was *probably not* in place already.

That's the best you can get from automation.